# Links produce 404 Error because wrong language

Tags: magento-1.7, language, 404

We have a magento store with two languages, german and english. The store default is english  and we have two different URL Keys depending on the language, for example:
English: www.domain.de/red-long-car.html
German: www.domain.de/rotes-langes-auto.html

So if someone types in the german link he goes to the default english store and then gets an 404 error.
Is there a way that Magento can redirect him to the german store without giving an 404 error.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One way to fix this would be to add URL rewrites in the backend for each product.
Inchoo published [an extension](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-extension-url-rewrite-importer/) to quickly import rewrites that might speed up the process